# How to set "," instead of some tag with XStream

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xstream

I have Person Object (for example), and when
i convert them to the XML file with XStream,
it's looks like this:

```
<person>
   <name>
      Bob
   </name>
   <accounts>
      <account>
         12345
      </account>
      <account>
         23456
      </account>
      <account>
         34567
      </account>
   </accounts>
</person>
```

I want to make it look like next file:

```
<person>
   <name>
      Bob
   </name>
   <accounts>
         12345,
         23456,
         34567
   </accounts>
</person>
```

Please tell me, if i can do this with XStream. And how can i do this?

Aliases can only replace one tag to another. I have tryed to use `registerLocalConverter` method for this, override marshal method in Converter class, and set parameters `(Person.class, "account", new PersonConverter());`
but I had no success. How can i change marshal method only for one tag, in case when i'm using `registerConverter` (not `registerLocalConverter`) method?

Please, help me. Thanks!

Comment: Show your Person class and its fields.